# What is the most user friendly way to verify an email address after user signed up on an app?

Tags: registration, mobile-application, email, verification

When a user signs up for for our app, he will have a limited access, and certain features won't be available to him.

When he tries to access any of these limited features, a pop up will show up saying he needs to verify his email first to access these features.

Then if he clicks he will get an email, with two options/buttons of "verify now" and "not my account".

Here is my question. When he clicks on"verify now" what do you think should happen? Which of these is the most user friendly approach?

Should he receive another email saying he is now a verified user.
Should the link open a web page saying he is now a verified user?
Should the link just launch the app?
Should the link launch the app with a popup saying he's verified now?
Should he receive an app inbox message saying he is now verified?
Should he get a push notification saying he is verified?
Or should nothing happen other then the back end gets updated?

Comment: My question refers to the additional step after verification email is sent. We decided that the verification will be emailed and user will have to clcik on the link that says" verify now". My question is what should happen once user clicks on that "verify email" link.  Thanks.

Comment: The most user friendly is to not verify ! so, the answer to your question lies in the realm of **why** you wanted to verify in the first place. The method chosen should be consequent with those reasons, from the most simple to the most complex, as the need for verification may be.

Answer (score 0):

When cliquing or touching "verify my email", you should open the website or app on a welcome page or welcome pop-in message. Depends on the purpose of your website/app. Most of the time you may link the "vérified email button" to user the account page with a welcome message. You may also load the website HP.

If the account création is asked during a journey, you should drive your user to help him to continue is action. Means in the right place he starts the account creation. Like "okay, this done. let's go next".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with a thank you page or interim step.  In most cases, the user just wants to get on with the show - so just take them to the features or status page.

If you really want to show the effect of a verified email address, you can add a closable Bootstrap alert box stating that their email address was verified, but show it on the page where you expect them to continue working.  Pop-up dialog box not needed.  Shortest path...